# Indexing audio for video editing

Tags: editing

What tools would you recommend to index the audio track for video editing? I'd like to be able to do a text search for words in the dialog to more easily locate video snippets. I'm using FC and/or Premiere.

Answer (score 2):

Premiere CS4+ has a feature called [Speech Search](http://library.creativecow.net/articles/weiss_roth_david/speech_search.php). I haven't used it personally, however, so I'm not sure of the quality. However, [this site](http://www.sparkminute.com/2008/12/04/how-good-is-adobe-premieres-search-speech-technologyeh/) has a sample of video, and also [a PDF of the transcription](http://www.sparkminute.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/TWINC_TestTranscript_11-21-08.pdf) Speech Search provided (they describe it as "eh").

Comment: +1. I've used this feature and I must say it's very hit-or-miss. It can only handle specific accents, and identification takes a long time.